# Guess the Number game python3 bugs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3. My game does work, but there are some bugs. For instance, if I input a number higher than 10, I still get "too high" statement, but as soon as I input a number after, I usually get "you got it!!". Also, try inputting the number 10 (or any number) over and over again and see the result. Sometimes it just crashes or doesn't print anything back.

Try and mess around with different int inputs, and you may understand what I mean by, there are a few bugs. The program doesn't return anything if I input the same number over and over again, but randomly, it sometimes says "you got it!!" after inputting the same number over and over again...

Any way I can improve my code? Thank you!!

```
import random

# Random number generator from 1 - 10 for simplicity.
num = random.randint(1, 10)

# User inputs their guess in the form of an int.
prompt = "Guess the number from 1 - 10: "
guess = int(input(prompt))

# Reaction print statements.
how_wrong = (["too high", "too low"])
correct = "you got it!!"

while guess != num:
    if guess > num:
        print (how_wrong[0])
        guess = int(input(prompt))

    if guess < num:
        print (how_wrong[1])
        guess = int(input(prompt))

    else:
        print (correct)
        break
```

Comment: You just need a `elif `

Answer (score 1):

Since the three conditions are connected, you want to use a `elif`.

You can also restructure your code so that it's not full of redundant `guess = int(input())`.

```
import random

# Random number generator from 1 - 10 for simplicity.
num = random.randint(1, 10)

# User inputs their guess in the form of an int.
prompt = "Guess the number from 1 - 10: "

# Reaction print statements.
how_wrong = ["Too high", "Too low"]
correct = "You got it!!"

while True:

    guess = int(input(prompt))

    if guess > num:
        print(how_wrong[0])

    elif guess < num:
        print(how_wrong[1])

    else:
        print(correct)
        break
```

Typically, you will use a `while True:` + a `break`, or a `while <condition>:` without `break`. They are never both needed. The first way allows you to not create a falsy condition beforehand.

Alternatively, in Python 3.8, you could use the walrus `:=` operator to assign a value to `guess` and check the condition in a single line.

```
while guess := int(input(prompt)) != num:

    if guess > num:
        print(how_wrong[0])

    elif guess < num:
        print(how_wrong[1])

    else:
        print(correct)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help! I just replaced the middle 'if' with 'elif' and it works fine. I also removed my redundant guess = int(input()) 's. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok lets start with some improvements:

- Case: input is not an int number (ValueError)
- Case: we got an unexpected interrupt (KeyboardInterrupt)
- Case: number not in between 1 to 10

Code example:

```
def read():
    try:
        number_a = int(input(f'Guess the number from 1 - 10: '))
        if number_a not in range(1,11):
            print('Number must be from 1 to 10')
            return read()
        return number_a
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard Interrupt I will now exit the program')
        quit()
    except ValueError:
        print('Give me an integer Number')
        return read()
```

now for the full Code:

```
import random


def read():
    try:
        number_a = int(input(f'Guess the number from 1 - 10: '))
        if number_a not in range(1, 11):
            print('Number must be from 1 to 10')
            return read()
        return number_a
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard Interrupt I will now exit the program')
        quit()
    except ValueError:
        print('Give me an integer Number')
        return read()


def check(guess):
    if guess > num:
        return answer[0]
    elif guess < num:
        return answer[1]
    else:
        return answer[2]


num = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = 0
answer = (["too high", "too low", "you got it!!"])

while guess!=num:
    guess = read()
    print(check(guess))
```

Comment: thank you! I have not yet learned about 'try' and 'except', but you've introduced it to me. I appreciate your help!